# Make NSDate Equal to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string:
`stringValue = 2013-06-11 06:01:28.`

When i try to convert it using NSDateFormatter it becomes like this: 
`date = 2013-06-10 22:01:28 +0000`.

I've read that they are the same point in time. In fact when i get the string value of the date, i get the string above.

If they're the same, is there a way to have a date with value equal to my string above? Can i have an NSDate *date = 2013-06-11 06:01:28? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because  when you convert string to date it convert to GMT time format

if you want date same as your string value than you have to set your stadard local time

Like

```
 NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc]init];
 NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [timeFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"]];
 [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"];
 date  = [timeFormat dateFromString:@"2013-06-11 06:01:28"];
```

hope it may help you

Comment: Do you know what timeZone does stringFromDate use? Why does it always return to the same value when we get the stringValue?

Comment: It uses the time zone set in the device settings by user.it give the stander time of zone that you provide.you may get list of time zone list useing NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);

Answer (score 0):

Use this formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter* f = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: if i have the same date with different format like maybe the other one is 2013-06-11 06:01:28 and the other one is 2013-06-10 22:01:28 +0000; will they return the same timeIntervalSince1970?